# Error showing in git push after reset --hard, fatal error non-fast forward

Tags: git

I want to remove two broken commits on a remote repository.

I used:

```
git reset --hard <commit_id>
```

So I could get back to the last commit I want to revert to. Then I applied the changes I made by pasting back the modified files I had, from an external folder (not in repository).

Now when I push back to the remote repository, it throws an error:

```
$ git push origin master --force
me@mydomain.com's password:
stdin: is not a tty
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/master (you should pull first
)
To ssh://me@mydomain/repos.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://me@mydomain/repos.git'
```

But if I pull again, the old commits I deleted using git reset would come back.

I tried using

```
git push origin master --force
```

Already but it still does not work.

How should I fix this so that I could remove commits from the remote, and append my new files back to it?

Thanks!

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

UPDATE:

on using `git push origin :master`
here is the output of the answer from qqx

```
$git push origin :master
stdin: is not a tty
remote: error: By default, deleting the current branch is denied, because the next
remote: error: 'git clone' won't result in any file checked out, causing confusion.
remote: error:
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyDeleteCurrent' configuration variable to

remote: error: 'warn' or 'ignore' in the remote repository to allow deleting the

remote: error: current branch, with or without a warning message.
remote: error:
remote: error: To squelch this message, you can set it to 'refuse'.
remote: error: refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/master
To ssh://me@domain.com/repos.git
! [remote rejected] master (deletion of the current branch prohibited)
error: failed to push some refs to ssh://me@domain.com/repos.git
```

Comment: Have you tried `git push origin +master`?

Comment: @Hasturkun using the `--force` option is equivalent to prefixing each branch to be pushed with `+`, so that wouldn't make any difference to what has already been tried.

Comment: @qqx: Ah well, the manual doesn't make that too clear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your remote repository likely has the `receive.denyNonFastForwards` setting 
enabled in its configuration. The docs for this option state:

> If set to true, git-receive-pack will deny a ref update which is not a 
>   fast-forward. Use this to prevent such an update via a push, even if that push 
>   is forced. This configuration variable is set when initializing a shared 
>   repository.

You may be able to get around this by doing:

```
git push origin :master
git push origin master
```

The leading colon on the branch name in the first command turns that into a 
request to delete the branch on the remote repository. After that is done 
pushing your current version of the branch would no longer be seen as a 
non-fast-forward push. But there's also an option which could be set on the 
remote repository to prevent the delete, `receive.denyDeletes`.

Comment: in a sense, what i want to achieve is overwrite the last two commits with my new commit.. will i be able to achieve that using this?

Comment: If deleting branches is allowed, the two commands would achieve basically the same as doing a forced push. So, yes you would be able to remove or replace commits from the remote.

Comment: can i disable the setting `receive.denyNonFastForwards` on the remote to make this work?

Comment: Yes, disabling that setting should allow your original push (with `--force` to work.